# how to make to icon web page running

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, favicon

I'd like to know how can I make the little web page icon on the left from the title "running" when I do, for example, a `getJSON()` to my external server to warn the user that his/her request is being treated.

Is there a way to control it?

Comment: Do you mean you want an AJAX progress animation? Maybe take a look at http://ajaxload.info/

Comment: page icon? do you mean _favicon_ ?

Answer (score 3):

Put a favicon link on the header of your page, e.g.

```
<link id="favicon" rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="/base-favicon.gif" />
```

when an ajax call starts, just change the `href` attribute of your favicon. Prepare an animated `gif`, then make a substitution with

```
document.getElementById('favicon').href = "/animated-favicon.gif";
```

when your ajax call has been executed (success or error) just restore the previous favicon